# angularjs - ui-router not displaying properly ($stateProvider)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set up my app. It was working fine, but then I had to change some URLs on the ui-router in order to have some sub-views.

Unfortunately, now, I cannot see all my pages properly and I don't understand why.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNQavV?editors=1010

Basically, I have different templates, and when URL changes, I display a different template into `appContent` view. Inside my details, I need to have a subView called `zone`, in which I can display `detailsOverview` template or `detailsEdit` template.

With my current setup,I'm not able to change page. Well, the page changes according to the URL, but `detailsOverview` is always displayed!

I think that the problem is somehow related with the subview rather than the URLs, but not 100% sure.

I'm pasting $stateProvider code here as well:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).config([
  '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
      name: 'app',
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/menuTemplate.html'
    }).state('app.details', {
      name: 'appDetails',
      url: '/:zoneID',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/mainDetails.html'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.details.overview', {
      name: 'appDetailsOverview',
      url: '/details',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/mainDetails.html'
        },
        'zone': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/detailsOverview.html'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.details.edit', {
      name: 'appDetailsEdit',
      url: '/edit/day/:timerEditDay',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/mainDetails.html'
        },
        'zone': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/detailsEdit.html'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.setup', {
      name: 'setup',
      url: '/setup',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/setup.html'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.about', {
      name: 'about',
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
          controller: 'aboutPageInfo'
        }
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/');
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with the `url: '/:zoneID',` in the `app.details` state you "swallow" all the possible parameters.

Thats means the url `#/app/about` and `#app/setup` URLs get also handled by the `app.details` state and don't seem to work.

In order to get them working, you have to define the `app.about` and `app.setup` state before the `app.details` state:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  name: 'app',
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/menuTemplate.html'
}).state('app.setup', {
  name: 'setup',
  url: '/setup',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/setup.html'
    }
  }
}).state('app.about', {
  name: 'about',
  url: '/about',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
      controller: 'aboutPageInfo'
    }
  }
}).state('app.details', {
  name: 'appDetails',
  url: '/:zoneID',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/mainDetails.html'
    }
  }
}).state('app.details.overview', {
  name: 'appDetailsOverview',
  url: '/details',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/mainDetails.html'
    },
    'zone': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/detailsOverview.html'
    }
  }
})
```

See the updated codepen with a working details and setup page:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKPyMd?editors=1010

Comment: From your updated pen, why it works with setup but not with about even if about is before details as well? Thank for the explanation i'm now just trying to understand a bit better :)

Comment: Yes, the about page seems not to work. I did not look into that problem... :)

Comment: Oh don't worry about it. it works in my real project. Thank a lot, I would have never figure it out myself!